# How view list of iOS tester's in-app purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Is there a way to view a list a my tester's in-app purchases? Ideally right on my phone.

I have tried:

Settings > App Store > scroll to Sandbox Account > Tap the user > Manage > Subscriptions box

It tells me that there are no subscriptions. That's correct since I didn't buy a subscription, but rather a one-time in-app purchase. But where can I see those?

How I made the purchase:

- I created a test user in App Store Connect.
- I logged into this account on my iPhone (Settings > App Store > scroll to Sandbox > signin).
- I installed my app via TestFlight.
- I made an in-app purchase. The purchase popup correctly shows the test user's email address and it's the test user's password that I have to enter.
- The purchase goes through. I get the standard "You're all set" message. I also get the Apple receipt (via the code, not in the phone's UI) that I can use to look up the purchase info.

BUT, where can I see a list of what purchases Apple thinks this user made? I'm specifically concerned about a case where I get an error message (and no Apple receipt), but Apple still shows the "you're all set" popup. I'd like to see whether this purchase actually went through to Apple.

I did see someone else ask this, but the question is 6 years old and has no answer (I said defensively before someone knee-jerked a "this has already been asked" close vote. sigh.).

Comment: There is no way to see TestFlight purchases apart from the receipt on the device.

Comment: If Apple shows the "Your purchase was successful" message, can I 100% trust that the user was (test/fake) billed? In my "purchase interrupted" test case, I'm getting the success message, but not seeing a receipt. I guess there's an error in my code where I'm supposed to pass that to my server...

Comment: The most important things to do you in your code: 1) Create a transaction queue listener in `didFinishLaunching` so that your app can handle incomplete transactions. 2) never call `completeTransaction` until you have successfully persisted the purchase using whatever technique you are using.